# javascript: Dragging a path element makes it unavailable

Tags: javascript, svg, path, svg.js

I have two elements in my test code. A closed path element and a rect element. I am using the svg.draggable.js library to drag both elements. The rect element appears to drag fine but the path element disappears when I click on it and try to drag it. Can somebody please explain what's going on and how I can make the path element draggable?

```js
< body >
  <
  div id = "curve" >
  <
  /div> <
div id = "drawing" > < /div> <
script id = "jscript" >
  var r = SVG('drawing').size(500, 500);
var p = r.path().attr({
  id: 'path0',
  padding: '0px',
  fill: 'blue',
  d: 'M0 0 C100 120 150 120 150 100z',
  stroke: {
    color: 'black',
    width: 1,
    padding: '1px'
  }
}).draggable();

var b = r.rect().attr({
  id: 'rect0',
  x: 300,
  y: 300,
  height: 30,
  width: 30,
  fill: 'red'
}).draggable(); <
/script> < /
body >
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
  <meta charset=utf-8 />
  <title>JS Bin</title>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/svg.js/2.6.5/svg.js"></script>
  <script src="file:///C:/Users/angular2/Downloads/svg.draggable.js/dist/svg.draggable.js">
    <!-- It does not appear there is any cdns location for svg.draggable.js library online. You will need to download it and install it locally if you would like to test the code -->
  </script>
</head>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please fix your snippet so that it runs.

Comment: Paul, the snippet won't run as is. It will need to be downloaded because it needs the svg.draggable.js library and I could not find a cdns for this library. The library will also need to be downloaded.

Comment: Please create a jsfiddle, load svg.js and svg.draggable.js as ressources so that it shows your issue. You can use raw.githack.com to get a link for the libs

Comment: @Learner You can use this link: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/svgdotjs/svg.draggable.js/master/src/svg.draggable.js

Comment: @Paul. I tried it with different browsers, including the production and the development links directly from raw.githack. I get the following error: "SyntaxError: import declarations may only appear at top level of a module"

Comment: Apologies. I realise now that my link doesn't work due to the wrong mime type.

Comment: Could one issue be that the svg.draggable.js site states that it requires svg.js > 3.0.10, however you are using 2.6.5?

Comment: @Paul, I tried with the updated svg.js  (3.0.11) - same error: "SyntaxError: import declarations may only appear at top level of a module".

Comment: I was able the solve the problem by creating a nested group, putting the path element in the nested group, and then making the nested group draggable rather than the individual element. The other problem that the svg.draggable.js is not accessible through a cdn or githack, etc., is still there, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able the solve the problem by creating a nested group, putting the path element in the nested group, and then making the nested group draggable rather than the individual element.